# Proceso largo en php, ejecutarlo en segundo plano

Tags: php, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Tengo un proceso en PHP que genera un fichero excel con unos datos calculados de varias tablas sql server. El problema es que al ser un proceso que tarda mucho (puede tardar mas de 10 minutos), el servidor siempre me devuelve un error "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded in ... "

Creo que lo mejor para este caso sería poder crear un proceso que genere el fichero Excel en segundo plano, y que pudiese informar de su estado. He leído algo sobre Gearman, pero desconozco como se implanta.

Comment: ¿Estás preguntando cómo solucionar tu problema y ejecutar tareas en segundo plano o cómo instalar Gearman? Ten en cuenta que Gearman puede ser una solución a tu problema, pero no la única. ¿Qué sistema operativo o de qué capacidades de planificación de tareas dispone tu servidor contratado? ¿Es un alojamiento compartido o un servidor dedicado (gestionado completamente por ti)? ¿Puedes instalar aplicaciones nuevas o entornos de ejecución nuevos o debe estar todo basado en PHP/MySQL?

Comment: Hola Oscar. El servidor es completamente gestionado por mi. Es un servidor en producción que gestiona una Intranet, con lo que es´ta enmi red local. Actualmente está basado en PHP, consultando datos de un SQL Server. No es que quiera Gearman, lo comento porque he leido que es una solucion al problema.  Me vale cualquier otro tipo de solución. Me imagino que lo normal es ejecutar el proceso en background, para no tener al navegador esperando y que de error por tardar mucho tiempo en finalizar el proceso. ¿que me aconsejas?

Comment: ¿Entonces usas un Linux para el servidor y un Windows para la base de datos o sólo Windows? Tanto Linux como Windows disponen de planificadores de tareas que te permiten ejecutar procesos en segundo plano. ¿Usas PDO/mssql, las funciones `mssql_*`, `sqlsrv_*` u `odbc_*`?

Comment: Uso un Linux para el servidor, y otro servidor Windows tiene la base de datos. Uso las funciones mssql.

Comment: Dime distribución y versión para enumerarte pasos de instalación del servidor y entorno de ejecución de línea de comandos junto con un breve script de uso y tarea de cron que necesitas agregar.

Comment: Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.81-2 i686

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.38-1~dotdeb+7.1

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58392/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-osbragon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Independientemente de como resuelvas esta situación necesitas ajustar [el time limit](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php) para que no se genere el error `Maximum execution time of XX seconds exceeded` ...

Por otro lado siempre puedes ejecutar tu script en línea de comandos y enviarlo al background: `exec("php -f mi_script.php > /dev/null &");` y entonces escribir en la base de datos el progreso del mismo conforme se va ejecutando. 
En el frontend entonces puedes tener un timeout en JS que consulte cada X tiempo el avance de tu script y que reporte el resultado a tu browser.