# PHP y postgrest Bloquea mi navegador

Tags: javascript, postgresql, php7

tengo un app web de gestion de clientes etc... al subir esta informacion masivamente mediante .csv...

usamos php7 para subir el archivo a una tabla de postgres sql.. luego de ahi ejecutamos funciones almacenadas para estraer los datos y repartirlos a distintas tables , numero, clientes...etc

cuando esto sucede el navegador o la ventada actual la que se usa para subir el archivo queda completamente bloqueado, no deja ni recargar, hasta que todos los procesos terminen..

Mi pregunta es: Como podriamos hacer para que esto pasa por debajo del servidor   , para que despues al momento de subir el archivo no se vea afectado el navegador, que ya el cliente puede seguir haciendo sus funciones

Disculpen si no entiendes o algo porfavor requiro sinceramente su ayuda , Gracias..

Comment: Si tienes dudas técnicas relacionadas a un código, deberías compartir ese código, o por lo menos la parte donde identificas el problema.
En este caso suena a que estás realizando una tarea síncrona que lleva mucho tiempo. Intenta hacerlo de manera asíncrona.

Comment: Por cierto, 'postgrest' no existe. Usualmente le llamamos 'postgres' al manejador PostgreSQL

Comment: Perdon por mi ortografia,, lo agredesco.

Answer (score 1):

Realiza el proceso en dos pasos:

1. Sube el archivo como lo haces hasta ahora
2. Ejecuta otro script para extraer los datos y enviarlos a otras tablas, con 2 opciones:

**Opción 1:** Ejecuta el script por medio de exec() en segundo plano. Acá mencionan cómo: [Proceso largo en php, ejecutarlo en segundo plano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68217/proceso-largo-en-php-ejecutarlo-en-segundo-plano)
Ventajas: Comienza a ejecutarse en cuanto subes el archivo
Desventajas: No está disponible en todos los servidores

**Opción 2:** Crea una tarea programada para ejecutar el script cada determinado tiempo
Ventajas: Prácticamente se puede configurar en cualquier servidor
Desventajas: Se ejecuta solo en los horarios que hayas especificado y estar pendiente de subir el archivo antes de que se ejecute